# leaflet renderLeaflet not working in shiny

Tags: r, maps, shiny, leaflet

I am working with leaflet package to draw maps and plot lat and long on the plot.
I am doing following in R.

```
m <- leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
addMarkers(lng=df_final$order_long, lat=df_final$order_lat)
m
```

It works perfectly fine in R console. But It doesn't work when I use it in shiny
This is my `ui.r` code snippet

```
tabPanel("Order Locations", leafletOutput("map", width = "80%", height =  
"80%"))
```

and this is `server.r` code snippet

```
 output$map<- renderLeaflet({

 dataset<-dataUpload()
 leaflet() %>%
 addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
 addMarkers(lng=dataset$order_long,lat=dataset$order_lat)
 })
```

It doesn't display anything. Where I am getting wrong. please help

Comment: Not much to go on. How about at least posting a example that "works fine in an R console"?

Comment: @Mike Wise I have already posted the code which works fine in R console

Comment: Oh, I see it does kind of work. Okay

Comment: Why are you calling `dataUpload()`? Is that a reactive object?

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), even if it's just fake data, would be useful.

Comment: `dataUpload <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, 'df_final.csv', read.csv)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works, I made it as close to yours as possible. It doesn't like percentage heights apparently:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("recalc", "New points"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Order Locations", leafletOutput("map",width="80%",height="400px")),
      tabPanel("Markers", verbatimTextOutput("markers"))
    )
  )
)

if (!file.exists("df_final.csv")){
  nmark <- 50
  hv <- 80
  df_final <- data.frame(order_long=runif(nmark,-hv,hv),
                         order_lat=runif(nmark,-hv,hv))
  write.csv(df_final,"df_final.csv",row.names=F)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dataUpload <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, 'df_final.csv', read.csv)

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(lng=dataUpload()$order_long,lat=dataUpload()$order_lat)
  })
  output$markers <- renderPrint({print(dataUpload())})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: I could make it look more like your example, but it is fairly close already. Do you want me to, or is this enough?

Comment: If u can that will be a great help.

Comment: Any chance you could accept it? Am trying to get to 3k today :)

Comment: Funny...but very true...leaflet is not a statistician...but a web developer.

Answer (score 2):

It Worked. Problem was with the `ui.r` file.

This is the modified code

```
tabPanel("Order Locations", leafletOutput("map"))
```

got rid off width and height parameters and it worked with default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat late to the party, but you can add your own CSS to control leaflet's aesthetics, typically in a `www` folder, e.g. `www/styles.css`, which has the added benefit of responding to changes to the size of the window.

```
  /* styles.css */
  div.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 45px; /* set to fit nicely with Shinydashboard's dashboardHeader(), adjust according to your own preferences. */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

and add this class in a `div()` in your `ui`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 actionButton("recalc", "New points"),
 mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
   tabPanel("Order Locations", 
            div(
             class = "outer",
             tags$head(
              includeCSS("www/styles.css")
             ),
             leafletOutput("map",width="100%",height="100%")
             )
            ),
   tabPanel("Markers", verbatimTextOutput("markers"))
  )
 )
)
```

The result:
[image]